# asp.net sql server how to tell if a stored procedure is terminated

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the following stored procedure that inserts 15 meter readings into a database.  The procedure works fine if there are no errors during the insert process.  Where I'm running across a problem is when duplicate records are inserted accidentally (violating the PK Constraint). In that case, the statement is terminated and my @InsertSuccess variable is not set appropriately.

Here is the stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insert_meter_readings] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @DateTime datetime,
    @MainCityMeasValue float,
    @ReheatMeterMeasValue float,
    @CasterOilMeasValue float,
    @MillCityMeasValue float,
    @NumOneMeterMeasValue float,
    @NumTwoMeterMeasValue float,
    @NumThreeMeterMeasValue float,
    @NumSixMeterMeasValue float,
    @MillWellMeasValue float,
    @MainWellMeasValue float,
    @SprayMakeUpMeasValue float,
    @MachMakeUpMeasValue float,
    @NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasValue float,
    @NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasValue float,
    @NumFiveBlowDownMeasValue float,
    @InsertSuccess int output

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @MainWellMeasNum AS INT = 42,
    @MainCityMeasNum AS INT = 43,
    @NumOneMeterMeasNum AS INT = 45,
    @NumTwoMeterMeasNum AS INT = 44,
    @NumThreeMeterMeasNum AS INT = 46,
    @NumSixMeterMeasNum AS INT = 47,
    @ReheatMeterMeasNum AS INT = 49,
    @MillWellMeasNum AS INT = 50,
    @MillCityMeasNum AS INT = 258,
    @SprayMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 348,
    @MachMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 349,
    @NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 372,
    @NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 373,
    @NumFiveBlowDownMeasNum AS INT = 374,
    @CasterOilMeasNum AS INT = 436
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO MainTable VALUES (@DateTime, @MainCityMeasNum, @MainCityMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @ReheatMeterMeasNum, @ReheatMeterMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @CasterOilMeasNum, @CasterOilMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @MillCityMeasNum, @MillCityMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @NumOneMeterMeasNum, @NumOneMeterMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @NumTwoMeterMeasNum, @NumTwoMeterMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @NumThreeMeterMeasNum, @NumThreeMeterMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @NumSixMeterMeasNum, @NumSixMeterMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @MillWellMeasNum, @MillWellMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @MainWellMeasNum, @MainWellMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @SprayMakeUpMeasNum, @SprayMakeUpMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @MachMakeUpMeasNum, @MachMakeUpMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasNum, @NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasNum, @NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasValue),
                             (@DateTime, @NumFiveBlowDownMeasNum, @NumFiveBlowDownMeasValue)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 15
    SET @InsertSuccess = 1
    ELSE
    SET @InsertSuccess = 0

END
```

And, just in case someone needs it, here is my code behind:

```
 int insertSuccess;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_insert_meter_readings", con))
        {
            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateTime", Session["curShift"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MainCityMeasValue", Session["mainCityMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReheatMeterMeasValue", Session["reheatMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CasterOilMeasValue", Session["casterOilMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MillCityMeasValue", Session["millCityMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumOneMeterMeasValue", Session["numOneMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumTwoMeterMeasValue", Session["numTwoMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumThreeMeterMeasValue", Session["numThreeMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumSixMeterMeasValue", Session["numSixmeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MillWellMeasValue", Session["millWellMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MainWellMeasValue", Session["mainWellMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SprayMakeUpMeasValue", Session["sprayMakeUpWellMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MachMakeUpMeasValue", Session["machMakeUpWellMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasValue", Session["numFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasValue", Session["numFiveMachMakeUpMeter"]));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumFiveBlowDownMeasValue", Session["numFiveBlowDownMeter"]));

            var returnParam1 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@InsertSuccess",
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int
            };
            com.Parameters.Add(returnParam1);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            insertSuccess = (int)com.Parameters["@InsertSuccess"].Value;

            if (insertSuccess == 1)
            {
                MessageLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
                MessageLabel.Text = "Insert Successful.";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                MessageLabel.Text = "There was an error with the insert.";
            }


            con.Close();
        }
```

When debugging I can see that the SP is terminating at the com.ExecuteNonQuery() line and my code doesn't advance to the insertSuccess = (int)com.Parameters["@InsertSuccess"].Value; line, so my message never gets displayed to the user.

My research only showed how to return a message from the SP with the IF @@ROWCOUNT block in the SP.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I had no idea; now I have a ton of renaming to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your stored procedure to include a `try catch` block so that you will always get a return value from it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insert_meter_readings] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@DateTime datetime,
@MainCityMeasValue float,
@ReheatMeterMeasValue float,
@CasterOilMeasValue float,
@MillCityMeasValue float,
@NumOneMeterMeasValue float,
@NumTwoMeterMeasValue float,
@NumThreeMeterMeasValue float,
@NumSixMeterMeasValue float,
@MillWellMeasValue float,
@MainWellMeasValue float,
@SprayMakeUpMeasValue float,
@MachMakeUpMeasValue float,
@NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasValue float,
@NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasValue float,
@NumFiveBlowDownMeasValue float,
@InsertSuccess int output

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
@MainWellMeasNum AS INT = 42,
@MainCityMeasNum AS INT = 43,
@NumOneMeterMeasNum AS INT = 45,
@NumTwoMeterMeasNum AS INT = 44,
@NumThreeMeterMeasNum AS INT = 46,
@NumSixMeterMeasNum AS INT = 47,
@ReheatMeterMeasNum AS INT = 49,
@MillWellMeasNum AS INT = 50,
@MillCityMeasNum AS INT = 258,
@SprayMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 348,
@MachMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 349,
@NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 372,
@NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasNum AS INT = 373,
@NumFiveBlowDownMeasNum AS INT = 374,
@CasterOilMeasNum AS INT = 436
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO MainTable VALUES (@DateTime, @MainCityMeasNum, @MainCityMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @ReheatMeterMeasNum, @ReheatMeterMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @CasterOilMeasNum, @CasterOilMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @MillCityMeasNum, @MillCityMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @NumOneMeterMeasNum, @NumOneMeterMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @NumTwoMeterMeasNum, @NumTwoMeterMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @NumThreeMeterMeasNum, @NumThreeMeterMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @NumSixMeterMeasNum, @NumSixMeterMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @MillWellMeasNum, @MillWellMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @MainWellMeasNum, @MainWellMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @SprayMakeUpMeasNum, @SprayMakeUpMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @MachMakeUpMeasNum, @MachMakeUpMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasNum, @NumFiveCitySprayMakeUpMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasNum, @NumFiveCityMachMakeUpMeasValue),
                         (@DateTime, @NumFiveBlowDownMeasNum, @NumFiveBlowDownMeasValue)

SET @InsertSuccess = 1

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH

SET @InsertSuccess = 0        

END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will mark this as the accepted answer as soon as I am allowed to.  Thanks again, I was unaware of TRY CATCH in T-SQL.